# Are stationary flying creatures considered "hovering" so that they do not fall when prone or incapacitated, etc?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, flight, prone

As the title suggests, I'm wondering if a PC race (for example, the [Variant Tiefling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/tiefling#VariantTiefling) with the winged option) would have the ability to hover in regards to the [Prone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Prone) condition.

The [Basic Rules state](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#FlyingMovement)

> If a flying creature is knocked prone, has its speed reduced to 0, or is otherwise deprived of the ability to move, the creature falls, unless it has the ability to hover or it is being held aloft by magic, such as the fly spell.

All the winged option for the Variant Tiefling states is

> **Winged.** You have bat-like wings sprouting from your shoulder blades. You have a flying speed of 30 feet while you aren’t wearing heavy armor. This trait replaces the Infernal Legacy trait.

From [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/148386/52137) we know a PC can stay in place in air.
However, since nothing states it has to *keep* moving to continue to fly, is it considered to have the hover ability? Specifically, if it is knocked prone will it fall or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You don't have to keep moving to fly.

Nothing in the [flying rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#FlyingMovement) requires you to keep moving to keep flying. The hover tag specifically allows a creature with a flying speed to stay aloft even when it is...

> knocked prone, has its speed reduced to 0, or is otherwise deprived of the ability to move

Any creature without the hover tag (like a Winged tiefling) would fall if it meets any of those conditions.